# Populate checkbox list from a database, and if previously checked then auto check on load

Tags: sql, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a user form which will populate certain categories based on fields stored in a database, this works all well and good using:

```
<%
DSN = "DSN=LocalSQLServer"
set panDB = server.createobject("ADODB.recordset")
panDB.open "select attribute_name,attribute_id,attribute_question_value from   attributes where attribute_type=6 and attribute_id>217 and attribute_id<250",DSN
Do while Not panDB.eof 
    response.write "<input type=checkbox value='" & panDB("attribute_question_value") & "' name='country_" & panDB("attribute_question_value") & "'>" & panDB("attribute_name")
    response.write "<BR>"
    panDB.MoveNext
loop%>
```

The table attributes is just a listing of various attribute_names, their corresponding attribute_type, and attribute_id. When one of these checkboxes is selected and the form is saved a second table is updated to record the form_attribute_id, form_id, and attribute_id. My problem is having the fields which were previously selected checked when the form is reopened. Any ideas?

This is what I've gotten so far for retrieving whether a field was checked or not, basically listing all of the fields in the category so that the checkboxes will all still be populated and then the idea is to have the checkbox checked if the attribute_id field is not null. I'm getting an object required error though at "if panDB("attribute_id") is not null then"

```
DSN = "DSN=LocalSQLServer"
set panDB = server.createobject("ADODB.recordset")
panDB.open "select a.attribute_question_value, s.test as 'attribute_id', a.attribute_name from attributes a left outer join (select attribute_id as 'test' from survey_attributes where survey_id=2091) s on a.attribute_id=s.test where a.attribute_type=6 and a.attribute_question_value < 4",DSN
Do while Not panDB.eof 
    if panDB("attribute_id") is not null then
        response.write "<input type='checkbox' checked value='" & panDB("attribute_question_value") & "' name='country_" & panDB("attribute_question_value") & "'>" & panDB("attribute_name")
    else
        response.write "<input type='checkbox' value='" & panDB("attribute_question_value") & "' name='country_" & panDB("attribute_question_value") & "'>" & panDB("attribute_name")
    end if 
        response.write "<BR>"
    panDB.MoveNext
loop
set panDB = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to devise a query which produced the output I was looking for in order to both populate the lists and have them checked depending on data stored. I realize the if statement could be cleaned up but I put it in there while testing.

```
DSN = "DSN=LocalSQLServer"
set panDB = server.createobject("ADODB.recordset")
panDB.open "select a.attribute_question_value, s.test, a.attribute_name from attributes a left outer join (select attribute_id as 'test' from survey_attributes where survey_id=" & survey_id & ") s on a.attribute_id=s.test where a.attribute_type=6 and a.attribute_question_value < 4",DSN
Do while Not panDB.eof 
    if panDB("test") > 0 then
        response.write "<input type='checkbox' checked value='" & panDB("attribute_question_value") & "' name='country_" & panDB("attribute_question_value") & "'>" & panDB("attribute_name")
    else
        response.write "<input type='checkbox' value='" & panDB("attribute_question_value") & "' name='country_" & panDB("attribute_question_value") & "'>" & panDB("attribute_name")
    end if 
        response.write "<BR>"
    panDB.MoveNext
loop
set panDB = Nothing
```

Comment: The real issue I had though was not with the checked attribute, it was with the correct sql query to return the field names and then determining that DB_Expression which I asked you about. I know I didn't give you alot to work with as far as what the structure of my tables are, but it was my query "select a.attribute_question_value, s.test, a.attribute_name from attributes a left outer join (select attribute_id as 'test' from survey_attributes where survey_id=" & survey_id & ") s on a.attribute_id=s.test where a.attribute_type=6 and a.attribute_question_value < 4" which solved my problem.

Comment: It's also not necessary to add the value "checked='checked', just plain 'checked' in the input section like I have it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the attribute `checked` and set it to true or false based on your DB value

```
"<input type='checkbox' " & (if (DB_Expression) then "checked='checked'" else "") & "value='" & panDB("attribute_question_value") & "' name='country_" & panDB("attribute_question_value") & "'>"
```

Don't forget quotes around `checkbox`

Comment: I've been able to get to this point, my problem lies in what the DB_Expression should be. I've tried using multiple recordsets to return the table fields I need but that's not working since I can't figure out how to compare the attribute_id from the attributes table with the attribute_id of form_attributes table.

Comment: @Phil When you submit the checked checkbox, you save this information in a second table you said. You're going to have to retrieve this information to determine if it was previously selected or not. This is what should go there

Comment: Thanks for the help @Shredder, I was able to get everything to work using the query in my post below. I used the "test" field to check if data was stored which corresponded to the current survey and added the "checked" attribute accordingly.